# How do I remove an element from the DOM, given its id?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

In this specific case, the element is a table row.

Comment: You could have at least shown how your HTML looks like and explain which row you need to delete based on what id.

Comment: @Darin: That probably wouldn't alter the answer - it's actually more useful if the question is generic, IMO.

Comment: @Bobby, it's not even clear what `Id` the OP means.

Comment: @Darin - does it matter if the id is "content", "red", or "my-elements-id"? Any which way, the method for removing it is exactly the same. Surely we don't want 1,000s of questions, all along the variant of "How do I remove an element with an id of 'content'?" ...

Comment: @Bobby, yes it does matter as it is not clear whether he is talking about the `id` attribute of a `tr` or some value stored inside for example the third `<td>` in this row. Depending on this the answers will be fundamentally different. See my point? Programming is an **exact** science.

Comment: Yes, I (and everyone else who's answered this question) assumed the asker meant the id attribute, rather than anything else. I think that's hugely likely, although I agree that it was badly worded (which is why I edited the question). If we've all got the wrong end of the stick, I'm sure the asker will come back and correct us.

Comment: @Bobby @Darin Ironically, the least activity has come from the stakeholder.

Answer (score 6):

Untested but something like:

```
var tbl = document.getElementById('tableID');
var row = document.getElementById('rowID');
tbl.removeChild(row);
```

or

```
var row = document.getElementById('rowID');
row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
```

Comment: You don't need a hardcoded reference to the parent.. you can get it from the row itself.. `row.parentNode.removeChild(row);` This way you only need the id of the element you want to remove ..

Answer (score 4):

```
var row = document.getElementById("row-id");
row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var zTag = document.getElementById ('TableRowID');
zTag.parentNode.removeChild (zTag);
```

Or in jQuery:

```
$('#TableRowID').remove ();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Jquery**

```
$('#myTableRow').remove();
```

This works fine if your row has an `id`, such as:

```
<tr id="myTableRow"><td>blah</td></tr>
```

**Pure Javascript :**

[Javascript Remove Row From Table](http://tech.chitgoks.com/2008/05/20/javascript-remove-row-from-table/)

```
function removeRow(id) {
  var tr = document.getElementById(id);
  if (tr) {
    if (tr.nodeName == 'TR') {
      var tbl = tr; // Look up the hierarchy for TABLE
      while (tbl != document &amp;&amp; tbl.nodeName != 'TABLE') {
        tbl = tbl.parentNode;
      }

      if (tbl &amp;&amp; tbl.nodeName == 'TABLE') {
        while (tr.hasChildNodes()) {
          tr.removeChild( tr.lastChild );
        }
      tr.parentNode.removeChild( tr );
      }
    } else {
      alert( 'Specified document element is not a TR. id=' + id );
    }
  } else {
    alert( 'Specified document element is not found. id=' + id );
  }
}
```

Comment: This requires the jQuery library.

Comment: yes this require j-query library i suggest this solution becuase its better to use for clean coding